# Need assistance with getting <td> value

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a table that shows the names of individual email templates. The email templates are being populated within a `mysql_fetch_assoc()` while-loop. The pseudo code looks something like this.

```
<table>
<?php 
$query = "......";
$example = mysql_query($query);
while(($var = mysql_fetch_assoc($example)))
{
    echo '
    <tr><td>'.$var[''].'</td></tr>
    ';
}
?>
</table>
```

Currently, one would notice that if I had a `<td>` ID, the ID would not be unique. Thus, pulling the value in javascript would be near disastrous.

My current thoughts involve using an incrementing php variable, and using that as the id name.

```
<table>
<?php 
$query = "......";
$somevar = "id"; //incrementing variable
$inc = 0;
$example = mysql_query($query);
while(($var = mysql_fetch_assoc($example)))
{
    $id = $somevar."_".$inc;
    echo '
    <tr><td id="'.$id.'">'.$var[''].'</td></tr> //<td> id theoretically should be unique
    ';
     ++$inc;
}
?>
</table>
```

Now, I'm still catching onto php and javascript. What I want to be able to do is click on an email template name, get the value (in this scenario the email template name), and pass it to another page using AJAX. I can cover the AJAX. I wanted to know if my current C.O.A. is heading in the right direction, or if I should try something else. Also, any thoughts on how I would obtain the value using Javascript?

Comment: Let me guess... Your database table doesn't have a primary key?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It does yes.

Comment: If your question is how to identify items, isn't that the obvious candidate? *(If that's not the question, you should rephrase it.)*

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, my question is still regarding getting <td> values in JS.  I'm just trying to figure out if what I'm considering doing is a good method of doing so.

Comment: You just updated your code according to my answer. It would be nice to let other users know.

Comment: @CBC_NS, Why not simply using it as an id then? You could simply add a prefix to it, like `'email-tpl-'`. Another option would be to add a `data-email-name="some_email_name"` attribute to the element holding the email name, so that when the element will be clicked, you can simply retrieve it's own `data-email` value (you could also read the innerHTML property if it's the same).

Finally, you could avoid relying on the DOM to hold data altogether and use an [MV*](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/) solution.

Comment: @Broxzier I acted a little too quickly there and didn't add an edit note.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need IDs at all to grab stuff from a clicked table row:

```
function getName(e){
  var cell = e.target;
  alert(cell.innerHTML);
}


window.onload = function(){
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for(var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    cells[i].onclick = getName;
  }
};
```

[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/asepeq/1/edit).

If you decide to use IDs, you need to use a unique identifier that's meaningful for both the current HTML document and the server-side code called by AJAX, so the obvious candidate is the DB table primary key.

Comment: I just wanted to add to this solution.  This works great, but i have two tables on the same page.  I ran into the issue that document.getElementsByTagName("td") would grab all td names when in reality all I needed was a specific set of <td> tags.  Instead I used

var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

Answer (score 0):

`$somevar` is an integer. You're using this to generate the unique ID's, however, an ID **can not start with a number**. I suggest adding a prefix for each ID. (`<td id="id_'.$somevar.'">`)

```
<td id="1">....</td>    <!-- wrong -->
<td id="id_1">....</td> <!-- right -->
```

As for your question, yes. You're going the right direction when this is fixed.

Have a look at [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

**EDIT**: The OP updated the code, the ID part has become irrelevant.